# Petición de Ajax se cancela

Tags: html, ajax

Al querer ejecutar una petición de Ajax para enviar datos y que se guarde en la base de datos, este se cancela y no envía ningún dato. Si necesitan otro dato para ayudarme, comentenmelo!

Aquí esta mi código de Javascript

```
function submit() {

var rfc = $("#rfc").val();
var razon = $("#razon").val();
var correo = $("#email").val();
var uso = $("#uso").val();

if(uso === "otr"){
    uso = $("#otro").val();
}

var datos = {
    RFC: rfc,
    Razon: razon,
    Correo: correo,
    Uso: uso
}

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: uri,
    data: JSON.stringify({ datosFactura: datos}),
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    error: function (xhr) {
        alert("error " + xhr)
    },
    success: function (data) {

        alert("Guardado")

    }
})
}
```

En mi formulario

```
<form>
            <div class="input-field col m4">
                <input type="text" id="rfc">
                <label for="rfc">RFC</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col m4">
                <input type="text" id="razon">
                <label for="razon">RAZON</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col m4">
                <input type="email" id="email">
                <label for="email">CORREO</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col m6">
                <select id="uso">
                    <option value="Por Definir">POR DEFINIR</option>
                    <option value="Gastos Generales">GASTOS GENERALES</option>
                    <option value="otr">OTRO</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col m6">
                <input type="text" id="otro" hidden>
                <label for="otro" id="labo" hidden>ESPECIFIQUE</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col m4">
                <input type="submit" class="btn-large" value="Guardar" id="agregar">
            </div>
        </form>
```

[image: Petición cancelada]

Comment: muestra tu formularion

Comment: @srJJ Listo, lo he agregado

Comment: listo bro, felicidades

Comment: Aún no lo resuelvo !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bajo mi experiencia, te digo que suele suceder que cuando se usa el `form` pero se abstrae con `jquery`, generea ese error, y en vista que lo que que capturas es solo precindir de la etiqueta `form` y poner el boton a la escucha y que invoque la funcion al asi:

```
//notese que la etiqueta <form> ya no esta

<div class="input-field col m4">
    <input type="text" id="rfc">
    <label for="rfc">RFC</label>
</div>
<div class="input-field col m4">
    <input type="text" id="razon">
    <label for="razon">RAZON</label>
</div>
<div class="input-field col m4">
    <input type="email" id="email">
    <label for="email">CORREO</label>
</div>
<div class="input-field col m6">
    <select id="uso">
        <option value="Por Definir">POR DEFINIR</option>
        <option value="Gastos Generales">GASTOS GENERALES</option>
        <option value="otr">OTRO</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="input-field col m6">
    <input type="text" id="otro" hidden>
    <label for="otro" id="labo" hidden>ESPECIFIQUE</label>
</div>
<div class="col m4">
//pones la funcion dentro de la funcion "onclick del input"
    <input type="submit" class="btn-large" onclick="submit()" value="Guardar" id="agregar">
</div>
```

me ceuntas como te fue...

Comment: Efectivamente era la etiqueta de form! Gracias!!!!!

Comment: Siempre es un placer compartir, ya que realmente yo dure buscando ese error durante 3 dias xD

Comment: si te sirvio vota a favor de ella :)

Comment: Listo!!!! :) Gracias

Comment: de nada bro, exitos